# Can I automatically stop operation that is too slow?

Tags: interruption

I need to write code like this: Do operation 1, but if it takes more that 5 seconds then stop it and do operation 2.
Is it possible to do this somehow without manual interruption?

Comment: You can try `TimeConstrained`. Example from help `TimeConstrained[Do[i^2, {i, 1000000}], 1]` will terminate computation if it takes more than one second. You can adjust the time as needed.

Comment: Thank you, TimeConstrained is what I actually need

Comment: Using `Names` is often useful. The first entry for `Names["Time*"]` would have answered your question.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `TimeConstrained` for this. Here is an example

```
tMax = 1;  (*second*)
f1[n_Integer] := Do[i^2, {i, n}];
TimeConstrained[f1[10^7], tMax]
(* $Aborted *)
```

You can use `CheckAbort` to check which function timed out or not, since `TimeConstrained` generated `$Aborted`. Here is an example

```
tMax = 5;  (*second*)
f1[n_Integer] := Do[i^2, {i, n}];
n = {10^1, 10^6, 10^8};
CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[f1[#], 5, Abort[]], "timed out!"] & /@ n
(*  {Null, Null, $Aborted}  *)
```

So the last one timed out, but not the first two. You can customize this more as needed.
(I need to find why the message "timed out" did not show up, but will look at this soon)

Comment: It looks like `CheckAbort` doesnt see the interrupt caused by `TimeConstrained`  (if you do Alt-. quick enough you get the `CheckAbort` expression .. )

Comment: @george2079 yes, something is strange with `CheckAbort` here. it should have returned the message. I posted a question on chat now about it. Not relevant to this answer, as one does not have to use it. But it is strange.

Comment: @Nasser - just found a horrible solution: `CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[f1[#], 5], ""] & /@ n /. $Aborted -> 
  "timed out!"`

Comment: @Nasser: `CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[f1[#], 5, Abort[]], "timed out!"] & /@ n`

Comment: @ciao This works!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the 3-arg version of [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained):

```
op1[time_] := (Pause[time]; Print[1]; 1)
op2 := (Print[2]; 2)
```

An example where `op1` doesn't time out:

```
TimeConstrained[op1[2], 3, op2]
```

> 1
>
> 1

Notice that `op2` never evaluates. Next, an example where `op1` times out:

```
TimeConstrained[op1[2], 1, op2]
```

> 2
>
> 2

This time `op1` was aborted, and so it didn't get a chance to print 1, while `op2` does evaluate and prints 2.